# get HSN Code in Pdf invoice in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, invoice

I tried searching online and contacting the plugin author, and he said that it can be retrieved using the WordPress get post meta.

I'm using a plugin called woo-gst to add a product attribute called 'prod_hsn_id' which add a filed called HSN code at product edit page, I'm also using a pdf invoice plugin called woocommerce pdf invoice to generate pdf invoice. Now I want to display the HSN code on the invoice.

````
    <?php foreach ( $this->order->get_items( 'line_item' ) as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = $this->order->get_product_from_item( $item ); ?>
        <tr class="product-row">
            <td>
                <?php echo esc_html( $item['name'] );
                global $wpdb;

                $hidden_order_itemmeta = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', array(
                    '_qty',
                    '_tax_class',
                    '_product_id',
                    '_variation_id',
                    '_line_subtotal',
                    '_line_subtotal_tax',
                    '_line_total',
                    '_line_tax',
                    '_wc_cog_item_cost',
                    '_wc_cog_item_total_cost',
                    '_reduced_stock',
                ) );

                $hidden_order_itemmeta = apply_filters( 'bewpi_hidden_order_itemmeta', $hidden_order_itemmeta );


                foreach ( $this->order->has_meta( $item_id ) as $meta ) {
                    // Skip hidden core fields.
                    if ( in_array( $meta['meta_key'], $hidden_order_itemmeta, true ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Skip serialised meta.
                    if ( is_serialized( $meta['meta_value'] ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Get attribute data.
                    if ( taxonomy_exists( wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( $meta['meta_key'] ) ) ) {
                        $term               = get_term_by( 'slug', $meta['meta_value'], wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( $meta['meta_key'] ) );
                        $meta['meta_key']   = wc_attribute_label( wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( $meta['meta_key'] ) );
                        $meta['meta_value'] = isset( $term->name ) ? $term->name : $meta['meta_value'];
                    } else {
                        $meta['meta_key'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', wc_attribute_label( $meta['meta_key'], $product ), $meta['meta_key'] );
                    }

                    echo '<div class="item-attribute"><span style="font-weight: bold;">' . wp_kses_post( rawurldecode( $meta['meta_key'] ) ) . ': </span>' . wp_kses_post( rawurldecode( $meta['meta_value'] ) ) . '</div>';
                }

                    $field_name = 'hsn_prod_id';

                    // then loop through items in order and print each custom field
                    foreach ( $this->order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                        if ( $product = $this->order->get_product_from_item( $item ) ) {
                            $location = $product->get_meta( $field_name );
                            if ( !empty($hsn_prod_id) ) {
                                echo '<div class="product-location">HSN Code: '.$hsn_prod_id.'</div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                ?>
            </td>```

above is the code In the Invoice Template file I'm trying to display the HSN Code.
````

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same today, did not find a solution, and finally here is what I did and it worked well.

We need to pull the data from `postmeta table`,  and to get that you need to have the `post id` for the `product`.

If you do `$product_id = $product->get_id()` this will return the `id (they call it Variation ID)`. The `post id` and `product id` are not same. 
To get the `post id` for the `product` you need to `subtract -1` form the `$product_id`.

This is the line you can use to get the HSN code :

`$hsn_prod_id = get_post_meta( $product->get_id()-1, 'hsn_prod_id', true );`

UPDATE:

The logic for `subtract -1` depends on the Wordpress,WooCommerce version may be. I have tried the same in a fresh setup where it didn't work. In there, I just used this `$product_id = $product->get_id()` value and it worked.

You can figure it by looking at the id for the product. The id it shows in the UI and the ID you see in the URL when you edit an order. If both are not the same you need to see the sequence difference and take a call.